# Opening the Google Plus snippet in a new tab or new window

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

When a user clicks on the +1 button, a snippet opens and gives the user the opportunity to post about her/his +1 on Google Plus.

Is there a way to make the snippet open as a new tab or new window instead of as snippet within the initial page where the +1 button was?

It must be possible, because that's how Sharethis (http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-tools) does it: when you click on the Google Plus button, it records the +1 and opens the snippet in a new page.

Anyone knows how to do something similar?

Thanks everyone in advance! Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like ShareThis is using the share URL which opens the share dialog in a new window. It will work as you describe, but it's not quite the same as the +1 button.

To use the share link, add a link element to your site that complies with the [Google+ Buttons policy](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/policy.html). Set the href attribute to `https://plus.google.com/share?url={url encoded share target}`

For example, linking to https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com will allow you to [share example.com on Google+: [image: Google+ share button]](https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com) (yes, that is a working demo).

Check out the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink) for more info.

If you use this approach please be aware of the fact that it is not a direct replacement for the +1 button. The link shares the target URL on Google+, but it does not actually +1 the target page. Only the +1 button can +1 a page.

Comment: Hi Jenny, thank you so much for your answer! Regarding the fact that doing this does not plus one the website, I believe it is easy to fix: I can use a +1 button and open the share?url=blablabla from the callback Javascript function :-) Thanks again!